# Angular, TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table

i'm trying to delete a row from a table. But i got an error that said `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` when i put the delete button at the end of a row. I followed this [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQ5z9SFBlek) , but i just need to make the delete button functional without load row data to the form.

```js
//service.ts
deleteProduct(key: string) {
  this.productList.remove(key);
}

//component.ts
onDelete(form: NgForm) {
  //fungsi deleteProduct()
  if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?') == true) {
    this.ProductService.deleteProduct(form.value.$prdKey);
    //this.resetForm(form);
  }
}

onItemClick(prd: Product) {
  this.ProductService.selectedProduct = Object.assign({}, prd);
}
```

```html
<!--the form-->
<form #productForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(productForm)">...</form>

<tr *ngFor="let product of productList">
  <td>{{product.prdName}}</td>
  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="onItemClick(product)" title="click to edit or delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Update</button></td>
  <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" *ngIf="ProductService.selectedProduct.$prdKey == null" (click)="onDelete(ProductService.selectedProduct.$prdKey)">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
```

The video tutorial version actually is `*ngIf="ProductService.selectedProduct.$prdKey != null"`. I made the `*ngIf="ProductService.selectedProduct.$prdKey == null"` so the delete button will appear at the end of the row without clicking a row first. Can anyone help me solve this? Please let me know if more snippets are needed. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `onDelete()` you are passing a key of `string` type but in `onDelete()` definition you are expecting it as **[NgForm](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm)** type.

Chnage `onDelete(form: NgForm) {` to `onDelete(key: string) {`

Try this

```
onDelete(key: string) {
  //fungsi deleteProduct()
  if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?') == true) {
    this.ProductService.deleteProduct(key);
    //this.resetForm(form);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lost of issues :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
        *ngIf="ProductService.selectedProduct.$prdKey == null" 
        (click)="onDelete(ProductService.selectedProduct.$prdKey)">
            Delete
</button>
```

1. `ProductService.selectedProduct.$prdKey == null` means shows delete when `$prdKey` is null ,
   so `onDelete(ProductService.selectedProduct.$prdKey)` this will always pass null to `onDelete`
2. `onDelete(form: NgForm)` , you has set param as `NgForm` , but you are getting `null` as explained above
3. `form.value.$prdKey` this line will throw error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

---

You should use  : `*ngIf="ProductService.selectedProduct.$prdKey != null"` as it is a perfect logic , and remove all the products with `$prdKey null`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
//component.ts
onDelete(key: string) {
  //fungsi deleteProduct()
  if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?') == true) {
    this.ProductService.deleteProduct(key);
  this.productList.remove(key);
    //this.resetForm(form);
  }
}
```